# PHP regex - extract a specific block among blocks

Tags: php, regex

I have four blocks :

```
<block>
Name data1
Spec 36
</block>
<block>
Name data2
Spec 22
</block>
<block>
Name data3
Spec 56
</block>
<block>
Name data4
Spec 41
</block>
```

And I try to be able to extract a specific block. The one with the name "data3" for exemple:

```
<block>
Name data3
Spec 56
</block>
```

I tried : `/<block.*?Name[\s|\t]+data3[\s|\t]+.*?<\/block>/ms`

But it takes also the previous blocks : https://regex101.com/r/oqKnMy/1

**UPDATE**

The example is not the good one. The blocks are :

```
<block>
Desc description of block1
Name data1
Spec 36
</block>
<block>
Desc a second description
Name data2
Spec 22
</block>
<block>
Desc something else
Name data3
Spec 56
</block>
<block>
Desc description of block4
Name data4
Spec 41
</block>
```

My test : https://regex101.com/r/zjU04w/1

**UPDATE 2**

I try now to do it with :

```
<block>
Desc description of block1
Name data1
<spec>
36
</spec>
</block>
<block>
Desc a second description
Name data2
<spec>
22
</spec>
</block>
<block>
Desc something else
Name data3
<spec>
56
</spec>
</block>
<block>
Desc description of block4
Name data4
<spec>
41
</spec>
</block>
```

Comment: try `\<block\>\nName data3.*?<\/block>`

Comment: Why are you inconsistently escaping greater than and less than symbols? Why are you providing resolving advice as a comment? This is what "answers" are for on this Q&A site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose this:

`/<\s*block[^>]*>[^<]+Name\s+data3[^<]*<\s*\/\s*block\s*>/g`

https://regex101.com/r/R0lKVC/1

Explanation:

- `\s` already includes tabs, new lines and white spaces. It's equivalent to `[\r\n\t\f\v ]`
- The multiline flag isn't needed. The `s` neighter, as I don't use the `.` (dot).
- Some spaces and attributes can be around the `<block>` tags so this is why I used `<\s*block[^>]*>` instead of just `<block>`. This is because `<block id="578">` or `< block class=important >` would also be valid *block* tags.
- Instead of using the `.*?` to match anything, I prefer using the `[^<]*` pattern that matches anything except the `<` char. This way you avoid using the ungready `?` option. But if you have child tags then my solution will no longer work. I don't know if you could have something like this:

  ```xml
  <block id="890" class="important">
    <description>Desc something else</description>
    Name data3
    Spec <spec>56</spec>
  </block>
  <!-- With child tags my solution will not work. -->
  ```

Comment: It works, thanks. But, I have updated the question and I try to do it with different blocks (blocks with `<spec>42</spec>` in the block).

Comment: @PeterEstiven: Well, I see the question changed many times! In this case, Wiktor and Mickmackusa have a better solution with the negative lookahead : https://stackoverflow.com/a/68681057/653182

Answer (score 2):

You need to use

```php
(?s)<block(?:(?!<\/?block>).)*?Name\s+data3\s.*?<\/block>
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VyUdyw/1). *Details*:

- `<block` - a literal text
- `(?:(?!<\/?block>).)*?` - any char, zero or more but as few as possible occurrences, that does not start `<block>` or `</block>` string
- `Name\s+data3` - `Name`, one or more whitespaces, `data3`
- `\s` - a whitespace
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars as few as possible
- `<\/block>` - a `</block>` substring.

Comment: @mickmackusa `\s` (that matches `\r`, `\n` and all whitespace chars (with `/u`, even those Unicode ones)) was chosen by OP. It is not very clear what the format is, it is not described, so the main point here is using the `(?:(?!text).)*?` tempered greedy token. The rest can be easily adjusted.

Comment: @mickmackusa I do not think we need to care for `\s` matching only one whitespace as `.*?` after it will match until the leftmost occurrence of the subsequent pattern (`</block>`). We might as well use `(?!\S)` instead of `\s` here.

Answer (score 0):

Hei, you need to close  `<block>` in the regex's first part

Try using this regex, for the data3 example

`<block>.Name[\s|\t]+data3[\s|\t]+.*?<\/block>`

[old demo](https://regex101.com/r/YMWnuQ/1)

EDIT OF POST EDIT

Try this new regex

`<block>\nDesc.*\s\S*Name data3.*\s\S*Spec.*\s\S*<\/block>`

[new demo](https://regexr.com/6392b)

Comment: Why are there pipes in your character classes?  Why write `\t` when your character class already contains `\s`? Just bad copy-pasting? Or do you not understand what these regex elements stand for?

Answer (score 0):

Use positive lookahead

```
<block>(?=([\t|\s]Name)\sdata3).*?<\/block>
```

Edit: https://regex101.com/r/58BaUj/1

Comment: Why are there pipes in your character classes?  Why write `\t` when your character class already contains `\s`? Just bad copy-pasting? Or do you not understand what these regex elements stand for?

Comment: Look at the OP's original question. Then take a look at your petty little comment again.

Comment: I saw that before I blew my whistle.  Do you understand what you are recommending thousands of future researchers to use?